# Java variable 'never used'

Tags: java

I am learning Java and currently attempting to combine if statements and multiple class files.
It is a simple I/O program with a twist, if *userName = JDoe* I want the program to say something other than the standard saying.

**From main.java:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        UInput uInput = new UInput();
        System.out.println("What is your name: ");
        uInput.setName(input.nextLine());
        uInput.saying();
    }
}

class ifMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String userName = "JDoe";

        if (test.matches("JDoe")) {
            System.out.println("You smell!");
        } else {
            UInput.saying();
        }
    }
}
```

**From UInput.java:**

```
public class UInput {
    private String userName;
    public void setName(String name){
        userName = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return userName;
    }
    public void saying(){
        System.out.printf("Hello %s", getName());

    }
}
```

However, in *class ifMain{}*, IntelliJ is saying *"Variable userName never used"*, what am I missing?

Comment: Why you `ifMain` class. It is not used anywhere & the notification you got is ovbious

Comment: You are not "missing" anything.  To contrary, the compiler is telling you that have a variable `username` which is _extra_ and is not being used.

Comment: you may forget to use `test.matches(userName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments:

```
class ifMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String userName = "JDoe";              // <=== Declared here

        if (test.matches("JDoe")) {            // <=== Not used here
            System.out.println("You smell!");
        } else {
            UInput.saying();
        }
    }
}
```

The local variable `userName` is never used in the `main` method of the `ifMain` class.

You probably meant:

```
        if (test.matches(userName)) {
```

---

Side note: The *overwhelming* convention in Java is that class names start with an uppercase character. So `IfMain`, not `ifMain`.

Comment: Okay, fixed that however am now getting: "Java: cannot find symbol" for test, and "non-static method" for saying()

Comment: @Pinguin_33: That would be a *different* question. The question you asked has been answered, if you have a different question, you can ask it. But before you do, just *look* at the code: Do you see `test` defined anywhere?

Comment: Apologies new to Stack, will look at the code and attempt to figure it out. Thanks for helping. Edit: Will switch to IfMain, Edit2: Wow can not believe I missed that....

Comment: Yes, I had attempted to do that when you had first answered my question however was told to wait,  then I became distracted and forgot to come back.

Comment: @Pinguin_33: Happens all the time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your program wouldn't even compile in first place. I believe that you are new to Java. But still, look at this code.

```
class ifMain {//Please change the class name to CamelCase convention
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String userName = "JDoe";

        if (test.matches("JDoe")) {// Compile error. Variable test is not declared.
            System.out.println("You smell!");
        } else {
            UInput.saying();
        }
    }
}
```

Are you trying in a notepad and executing it? You can try using eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ IDEs in that case to help you better.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. I had test defined,  must have deleted it at some point. Fixed and is working.